# How catch(intercept) and hide a UserNotificationCenter's message ("The disk was not ejected properly")?

Tags: objective-c

I know that I can stop the UserNotificationCenter service temporarily, but this is a bad way. Perhaps, if the a different programmably way to hide or to intercept this message without stopping the service?

Answer (score 1):

Found this here (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1141582), and it works for me in MacOSX Lion:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserNotificationCenter.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to cancel a `UserNotificationCenter` message, you need the associated `CFUserNotificationRef` object, which you're unable to get because you're not the process that originally created the notification.

Comment: So, maybe I can catch alert window("The disk was not ejected...") and click "OK"? Are there other possible approaches?

Comment: My point is, I don't think there's any way for you to do this (nor do I think it's appropriate to try).